# Receiving 415 Error for ajax call with formData

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, multipartform-data, form-data

I'm trying to send the ajax call with formData contains list of image files & some strings. But the call is failing with error 415.

Below the code.

```
var file = picChooser.files[0];

var jobExecutionImagesContext = new FormData();
jobExecutionImagesContext.append('file', [file, file]);
jobExecutionImagesContext.append('apptId', '123456789rt78');
jobExecutionImagesContext.append('keyPrefix','images/start');

 var request =  new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('POST', "/example/images", true);
  request.addEventListener('error', function(response) {console.log("failed ajax call: {}", response); }, false);
  request.addEventListener('load', function(response) {console.log("suceeded ajax call: {}", response);}, false);
  request.addEventListener('abort', function(response) {console.log("failed ajax call: {}", response); }, false);
 request.send(jobExecutionImagesContext);
```

Code in java controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value = {"/example/images"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String capturePhotos(final HttpServletRequest request,final HttpServletResponse response) {
```

Comment: That means the server does not support sending form data.

Answer (score 0):

415 error code is Unsupported Media Type. You didn't set a content type. Set your content type to `'Content-Type' : 'application/json'`.

Comment: Yes, I also tried that but call is failing with error 400

```
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```